# re-submitting a patch in Linux kernel

Tags: git, linux-kernel, submit, patch

When I submit a `patch` in the Linux kernel subsystem, for example, netdev, where there exist two trees, `net.git` and `net-next.git`, `net.git` is normally for bug fixes, and mistakenly submitted a bug fix  in `net-next.git`, am I supposed to re-send it with subject as in `[RESEND PATCH net.git ... ]` ?

Comment: I don't think stackoverflow.com is the good place for this question. Perhaps you should more contact the maintainer or ask in the mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When re-sending a patch, you use v1 for the first resend, and any for other re-sends, you'll increment the number by 1.

Guideline:

```
[PATCH v1] folder-name: subject-name
```

An Example of a patch I resent twice:

```
From 57162b5cf23aa94f9902317f84c473a523f1bdf8 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Kitone Elvis Peter <elviskitone@gmail.com>
Date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 13:09:07 +0300
Subject: [PATCH v2] block: Use SPDX License Identifier

There is need to identify a license in source code files
for open source software.

Signed-off-by: Kitone Elvis Peter <elviskitone@gmail.com>
---
 drivers/block/brd.c | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

diff --git a/drivers/block/brd.c b/drivers/block/brd.c
index 66cb0f8..4f998ed 100644
--- a/drivers/block/brd.c
+++ b/drivers/block/brd.c
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
 /*
  * Ram backed block device driver.
  *
-- 
2.7.4
```

Comment: I think the 'first resend' should be tagged with v2 not v1. Check https://kernelnewbies.org/PatchPhilosophy